# Escaping double quote and comma in shell

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-ec2

the command below will give the volumes of my Amazon instance

`aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-west-2 --instance i-cbd35513 | grep -e "VolumeId" | cut -d ":" -f 2`

and the output of that command is:

```
"vol-f6be8636",
"vol-69be86a9",
```

But, I want the output

```
 vol-f6be8636
 vol-69be86a9
```

Can anyone please show me or give me an example of how to do it? I would really appreciate of your helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-west-2 --instance i-cbd35513 |
awk '/VolumeId/{gsub(/[",]+/, "", $2); print $2}'
```

There is no need to have `grep` and `cut` now since my suggested awk command will do all the 3 jobs.

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest ways is to use `tr`:

```
other-commands | tr -d '",'
```

Meaning, `tr`, delete, then the characters to delete, inside single
quotes so the shell doesn't interpret them.